# Two .aspx pages using the same .cs file, good idea?

Tags: .net, asp.net, code-reuse

There are similar posts here. I just want to clarify something. I implemented this in a test project. I created two pages page1.aspx and page.aspx are copies of each other except names. I configured them so that they use the same backend coding file.

page1.axpx -> page.aspx.cs
page2.aspx -> (above code)

My question is,

1. is it it a good idea to avoid extra code and enhance maintenance?
2. While everyting works in test project above. In my actual project, I get this very common error

**The name 'xxxx' does not exist in the current context asp**

The code will not compile because of the above error. If I run the application from the browser, it does work (or seems to be). My question is, why I am not getting this error in one application and not the other. This issue has been fixed now. But want to why I get this error in the first place and then playing with it here and there, the error disappears.

**I believe this really is a Microsoft bug. How? I explain it here.**

Page1.aspx.cs is really using Page.aspx page and not page1.aspx controls. The intellisence show only Page1.aspx controls (if u add control to page2, it wont be shown in intellesense, if you add it to Page1, it will be shown). Since the controls on both the pages are exactly the same (including names and IDs), they miraculously work. Sometimes the compiler don't like it and will give you error (for no apparent reasons). Microsoft should address these issues more elegantly and not throw it on us.

So it is solved for me but can anyone explain this mysterious behavior.

Comment: can you give some context on why you need two pages that are identical?  breaking things out in shared code as mentioned in the answers makes a lot more sense generally, but i am having a hard time picturing the need for two identical pages in the same app.  perhaps we could give some specific ideas if we had more information. :)

Comment: This is role based application. The code was given to me, I did not write it. I do thing user control was the way to go. But here my main issue is why this behavior is so *not standard*. Bug one time, fix the other time. This is so obvious there will be issues when you you use one source file for two pages. Can anyone comment on "I believe this really is Microsoft bug" and below. Thanks

Comment: IMO i think once you start using things in a way other than they were intended, it's more like: this is undefined behavior because the app is trying to do something that was never intended to work.  the fact that it works sometimes doesn't mean it's a bug when it doesn't.

Comment: Well no ware in documentation it says, don't do it. If it works, it should work in a standard way. This is just bad example of how Microsoft keeps its product. Since this was not a major bug people can see, they fail to spend any time on it to fix it to save money and save the developer's brain. Been worked in Microsft, know how things are.

Comment: it would be impossible to list all the ways that you're not supposed to do something. more to the point is nowhere in the documentation does it suggest that what you are trying to do is supported. as for "if it works, it should work in a standard way" how do you propose that they do this? test all the things that they don't tell you that you can't do and make sure they fail? there's no way to know for sure all the ways people will use things incorrectly. had you re-worked the pages using documented methods instead of spending time debugging this undocumented use, it would have worked.

Comment: I believe this is a very common practice and Internet is filled with solutions to this problem, no ware it says, this is wrong practice to do in the first place, including the gurus from Microsoft. This is not even .NET 1.0, we are talking about. Think about OOP and encapsulation and all those nice things so you can't access or modify something my mistake. What is the use of this complicated technology, if you can't put it to use.

Comment: people do put it to use, as documented and apparently as undocumented.  if it works, great.  but, ok, if you are so certain this is a bug as opposed to an unsupported usage of the tools, then just add your support to an existing bug report on https://connect.microsoft.com/ or add it as a new bug report if none exists.  they tend to be quite responsive. no need to post here trying to make a point, this is a place to get help, not to voice your issues with microsoft.

Comment: filed it with Microsoft, response is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not truly supported by Microsoft

I discussed this with Microsoft and here is what I got from them.

`After further investigation, here are the results. Due to the manner in which Intellisense works, we cannot support Intellisense for scenarios involving a shared code behind on the aspx.cs files. There are two different approaches that one can take to deal with this scenario. The option supported in VS is using either AppCode or UserControll for the common code elements and then calling those methods to achieve a common code base. The second option involves using the CodeBehind in the manner that you are currently using it (without Intellisense), and assuming that the code is correct with respect to both design pages, the code should compile correctly since it is an ASP.NET supported scenario. Thank you for your feedback.`

So here what that means

1. Intellisense will not work with both the pages, but only with one page
2. your code will compile only if both the controls are on both the pages!

This really is against the idea of having a shared codeBehind file. My scenario will most likely be two slight different pages which uses same code behind. But for Microsoft, two slightly different pages, can not use the same codebehind file

Ideal Scenarios should be

1. Intellisense should pick controls in both the pages
2. Code should compile if the the control that is accessed is present in either of the two pages.

Answer (score 8):

Its better to put the stuff in one [user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) and use that user control in both pages. Maintenance will be much easy by doing this.

Comment: +1 Agreed.  You should be using UserControls for this or breaking shared code out to a separate class.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should let the pages have their own code behind files, and put most of the duplicated code in a separate class that you can use from both pages.

The reasoning behind this, is that it's easy for someone who is not deeply involved in the project (like you, a few months from now...) to edit the code behind without realising that it affects more than one page.

---

When you manually change the class names in pages or code behind files, the hidden design file that contains a partial class might not be updated. You can get to the hidden file by searching for the class name in the project, or by clicking an error message that leads to the file.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely fine to use a class shared between pages. It has been in use for a while. However the best approach would be; if you create a base class and inherit that class instead of System.Web.UI.Page:

See the following links:

1. https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/041305-1.aspx
2. http://aspalliance.com/63_Base_Page_and_User_Control_Classes

Good Luck

Comment: of course you can. I am talking about the idea of two slightly *different* pages sharing the same codebehind which is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Class Name = CsForAllPages.cs 
Content :

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
public partial class general : System.Web.UI.Page
{
        // Your Same Code For all .aspx Pages
}
```

in the next in aspx pages set

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="~/CsForAllPages.cs " Inherits="general" %>
```